# Select data from a nested jsonb array in Postgres

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, jsonb

I want to select the last value from an array nested like this:

```
{ tier: [
  { tier: [] },
  { tier: [] },
  { tier: [
      { tier: 1},
      { tier: 2},
      { tier: 3}, // < this item       
    ] 
  },
  ] 
}
```

I've tried to use something like this from other examples, but the syntax is eluding me. 
I either get a 'column does not exist' or 'cannot extract elements from object'

```
SELECT *, 
  t0->tier->(jsonb_array_length(t0->tier) - 1) t1,
  t1->tier->(jsonb_array_length(t1->tier) - 1) t2,
  t2->tier->(jsonb_array_length(t2->tier) - 1) t3,
FROM data t0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reference it by negative index:

```
SELECT t -> 'tier' -> -1 -> 'tier' -> -1
FROM data;
```

The -1 here references the last item of the array, which means you don't need to calculate how many elements there are.

Comment: I suspect that OP wants: `js -> 'tier' -> -1 -> 'tier' -> -1 ->> 'tier'`, which gives the value of the last element rather than the object itself. +1 anyway.

Comment: Ah, that wasn't clear to me.  Thanks for adding this clarification.